# Choppy edges with sub pixel movement MonoGame/XNA 4

Tags: xna-4.0, monogame

When I move a texture slower that one pixel it moves using sub pixel movement inside but the edges jumps from pixel to pixel.

Video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zcai1PUfzzA

Sorry for the low quality (Its hard to see), I'm using linear filtering. How do I fix it so everything moves smooth?

```
spriteBatch.Begin();
spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, Color.White);
spriteBatch.End();
```

Comment: I think this is because I dont have enought space on the image so it can blur the edges, anyone know how I can allow the image to scale without adding a trancperant frame around my img?

Comment: What does your draw code look like?

Comment: Jzx it looks like this spriteBatch.Begin(); sprite batch.Draw(texture, position, Color.White); spriteBatch.ENd();

Comment: The coordinates of `position` might be getting rounded to integers before that. This can also happen if you're using the Rectangle based version of `SpriteBatch.Draw`. So how are you setting `position`?

Comment: jzx Im chancing the Vector2s X and Y values

Comment: I fixed it by using a transparent frame around my image, It didn't have enough space to be able to blur the edges so in juped from pixel to pixel to prevent the image from being scaled

Comment: Any idea of how I can go about doing this without adding transparency?

Comment: Your YouTube video is "private". I cannot view it.